How do I manage branches with Tortoise SVN?
In my team we are versioning a project with SVN for the first time and are having problems with syncing our work.
How do I create branches? Currently, after having done "Check-out" I have a folder with withing "branches", "tags" and "trunk".
Inside this folder I go right-click and select "Branches/Tag...", then enter the URL /branches/newBranch1.
After updating to sync with the server the new branch appears in the branches folder.
Problem is: inside this branch there's a copy of trunk, branches and tags. Is this normal?
Furthermore, when someone opened a second branch with URL /branches/newBranch2, after updating to sync with server this will be containing /branches/newBranch1 as well in a strange recursive pattern. I'm facing multiple recursive folders and don't know to manage this
I tried opening the repo-browser and correcting from there but to no avail.
Edit: The checkouts didn't include "/trunk" at the end and neither the location to branch from. Was it necessary?

How did you check out? You probably omitted trunk from the URL from which you checked out. Same problem for creating branches, you want to copy from trunk to branches/newBranch1. Please [edit] and describe the exact steps you took.
